# DataTables How To get the value at clicked row and 1st column?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to create an edit button for all rows, therefore I need the ID of the row (which is in the 0th column). How can I get that?

Pseudocode:

```
 "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<a type='button' name='edit' class='editbutton' href='vykresy/edit/'.[DATA of first colum and current row here]>Edit</a>"
        } ],
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a custom render function, then you can use the 'full' argument to access any property of the row.

```
"columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta){
            return "<a type='button' name='edit' class='editbutton' href='vykresy/edit/" + full.ID + "'>Edit</a>";
        }
    } ],
```

Comment: Almost good, but what do I put instead of the ID in full.ID ? the Column header name? number 0 (as in 1st column)? I dont have any variable as ID.

Comment: I edited my render like this:  `"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                return "<a type='button' name='edit' class='editbutton' href='vykresy/edit/" + table.cell( data,0 ).data() + "'>Edit</a>"
            }
        } ],` but I get the ID of the first row of the page (if 10 rows are shown then I get number 1 on first page, 11 on second), I need to get the data of the first column of the row I clicked on

Comment: Try changing from 'full.ID' to 'full[0]'